# Why am I blocked from reviewing?

Tags: support, reviewing

I wanted to do some reviewing, when I got the following message:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. Take a break and come back in 3 days.

Why did I get this message, and how can I find out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a closer look at your review history. Yesterday, you had 20 first posts reviews, and for all of them, your selection was No Action Needed.

The First Posts review queue serves two functions: the first, which I believe you're checking for, is whether the post has any quality or content issues that require flagging.

The equally (if not more) important second, however, is to help users by giving them feedback on their posts, and this is the component of these reviews that seemed to be missing. This second purpose is the reason upvoting, commenting, and editing lead to a Reviewed state on a user's first post.

By editing, you can help introduce users to MathJax, and help make their posts pretty, raising the quality standard for new posts on the site. By voting, you tell the user that their post is either appreciated or not appreciated. By commenting, you can give all manners of feedback to the user. All these - and more, adapting to a new user's needs.

In other words, we want people to have the most enjoyable experience on this site that they can, and helping them improve their posts is a *huge* part of that.

Selecting No Action Needed implies that the user's post is completely fine - it doesn't need edits, has nothing that could benefit from helpful commentary, and also doesn't need voting feedback.

While this is true of possibly one or two posts once in a while, it's certainly not true of 100% of them, and I think if you look through your review history you'll find this is true, too.

Hopefully this helps you better understand the purpose of the First Posts review queue, and we look forward to seeing constructive reviews in the future!

Comment: Is there a way to compare my review to the other reviews of the same post, preferably for a list of posts at once?

Comment: @SQB Nope! You're the one and only one person who got to review these posts. Otherwise, you'd see a list of other reviews, like you do [on suggested edits](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2904) and [on close votes](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/close/2669). That's part of what makes the individual First Posts reviews particularly valuable. If you have questions about specific reviews, though, I'd be happy to help with those.

Comment: Well, I'm going through the list again, reassessing. I'll edit the outcome into my question.

Comment: @SQB It's very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

[Because this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history?userId=68):

[image: screenshot]

Every one of your First Posts reviews were "No Action Needed," and many were in quick succession. I went through and quite a few of them could indeed use some sort of action, whether it be an edit, comment, vote, or something else.

Please consider each review carefully and avoid "robo-reviewing." The queue exists for a reason, and simply clicking "No Action Needed" on everything defeats the point. By pushing everything out of the queue, you're not letting posts by new users get the attention that they need.

Comment: And better practice would be to select "skip" if you don't feel you want to (or can't properly) review the entry.